# React table V7 - detect Expanded Change

Tags: reactjs, react-table

In React-table V6 we had a props - onExpandedChange, we could pass a func that would get executed  when expansion was changed, how do we achieve same in react-table V7

Answer (score 3):

You can leverage the `stateReducer` option when creating the `useTable` instance. Something like this will take the expanded items from the `prevState` and remove them from the `newState`. There may be more elegant solutions but this worked for me in a pinch.

```
const stateReducer = useCallback((newState, action, prevState) => {
    // intercept expand toggles and collapse other expanded row(s)
    if (action.type === 'toggleRowExpanded') {
        const prevTokens = Object.keys(prevState.expanded);
        const newTokens = Object.keys(newState.expanded);

        if (newTokens.length > 1) {
            const nextExpanded = {};

            for (const t of newTokens) {
                if (!prevTokens.includes(t)) {
                    nextExpanded[t] = true;
                }
            }

            return { ...newState, expanded: nextExpanded };
        }
    }
    return newState;
}, []);
```

Then pass `stateReducer` into your `useTable` instance:

```
const {
    getTableProps,
    getTableBodyProps,
    headerGroups,
    rows,
    prepareRow,
    visibleColumns
} = useTable(
    {
        columns,
        data,
        stateReducer
    },
    useExpanded
);
```

Answer (score 0):

sinha, I didn't find any method to detect expand change but you can make use of the expanded object as it provides the status of expanded rows

```
const {
    state: { expanded }, // this will give you row/nested-row id with status
  } = useTable(
    {
      columns: userColumns,
      data,
    },
    useExpanded // Use the useExpanded plugin hook
  )
```

[image: Row expanded]

Example : [Sandbox   react table exapandables](https://codesandbox.io/embed/github/tannerlinsley/react-table/tree/master/examples/expanding)

Comment: Thanks but I want to trigger a function when expansion changes.